# Undefined offset after returning result to a function, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, offset

My result from a SQL-query is saved in the variable `$res`.

A `print_r()` from `$res` says this, which is ok (I think):

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [hoejdemeter] => 1152 [laengde] => 24120 ) )
```

The `$res` is returned to a function and looped over to get the two variables:

```
foreach ($Data as  $value) {
    list ($length, $hight) = $Data;
}
```

Then I get this problem:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\BjergCykel1.php on line 95

What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: PS: Its "height" not "hight".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do not use `list`:

```
foreach ($Data as  $value) {
    $hight  = $value['hoejdemeter'];
    $length = $value['laengde'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is with using `list` with an associative array. The [`list` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) clearly states:

> list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

Your array has the two string keys `hoejdemeter` and `laengde` instead of the numerical indices `0` and `1`.

The cleanest way to retrieve the data would be:

```
foreach ($Data as $value) {
    $height = $value['hoejdemeter'];
    $length = $value['laengde'];
    //... Do something with $height and $length inside the foreach
}
```

Using a function fo retrieve the values instead of using the keys and assigning them manually just makes your code less readable and should not be done in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you construct a minimalist example that shows the error like so:

```
<?php

 function test($data){
                print_r($data);

                foreach ($data as  $value) {
                list($length, $hight) = $value;
                    echo("DEBUG: $length, $hight\n");
                }
        }

        $data=array(array ("hoejdemeter" => 1152, "laengde" => 24120 ) );
        test($data);

?>
```

Output then is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hoejdemeter] => 1152
            [laengde] => 24120
        )

)
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /tmp/foo.php on line 7
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /tmp/foo.php on line 7
DEBUG: ,
```

I guess what you wanted to do instead was:

```
<?php

 function test($data){
                print_r($data);

                foreach ($data as  $value) {
                print_r($value);
                list($length, $hight) = array_values($value);
                    echo("DEBUG: $length, $hight\n");
                }
        }

        $data=array(array ("hoejdemeter" => 1152, "laengde" => 24120 ) );
        test($data);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hoejdemeter] => 1152
            [laengde] => 24120
        )

)
Array
(
    [hoejdemeter] => 1152
    [laengde] => 24120
)
DEBUG: 1152, 24120
```